# How to get rid of circular references to java objects?

Tags: java, object, recursion, graph, circular-reference

I am very new to programming trying to learn it all by myself. I am facing an issue that I can not resolve and I couldn't find any good answers online.

I have a series of classes implementing an interface, one of which needs to provide a reference to any of the other types of objects. I post a simplified version of my code below, I know it might not be all correct but I hope you can understand it.

What my problem is that I am not able to write a method that gets rid of these kind of circular references like in the main method I posted below. I read a lot of things, about graph and recursive algorithms, but I couldn't find out an answer yet. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
public class ReferenceObject implements A {

    A reference;

    public void setReference(A reference){
        this.reference=reference;
    }

    public Object getValue(){
        return reference.getValue;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReferenceObject r1 = new ReferenceObject();
    ReferenceObject r2 = new ReferenceObject();
    ReferenceObject r3 = new ReferenceObject();
    r1.setReference(r2);
    r2.setReference(r3);
    r3.setReference(r1);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to get rid of circular references.  Once r1 - r3 go out of scope, they'll be garbage collected.

Comment: I don't understand your need. What do you try to implement ?

Comment: Are you talking about [detecting a cycle in a graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph)?

Comment: The first question isn't "how" but "why".

Comment: Maybe I asked the question wrong. I need to detect it, not necessarily get rid of it. Yes, it is kind of like detecting a cycle and than displaying some error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is fairly simple:

```
public class ReferenceObject implements A {

  A reference;

  public void setReference(A reference) {
    this.checkForCircularRef(reference);
    this.reference=reference;
  }

  public Object getValue(){
    return reference.getValue;
  }

  private void checkForCircularRef(A reference) {
    if(reference != null) {
      A nextRef = reference;

      while(nextRef != null) {
        if(nextRef.equals(this)) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Reference refers back to this object!");
        }

        nextRef = reference.reference;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

The `checkForCircularRef` method essentially does a linear search for a reference to the the calling object (`this`). More complicated structures might need to a more complex search.

If your objects have pre-existing circular references, you will probably need to keep the references in a data structure, and check that you have not seen each reference you encounter previously, or the code I provided will get stuck in an infinte loop.

Comment: Thank you! With a little changes i got this working. :)

Answer (score 0):

> **I have a series of classes** implementing an interface, one of **which needs to provide a reference to any of the other types of objects**. **I post a simplified version of my code below**, I know it
>   might not be all correct but I hope you can understand it.
>
> What my problem is that **I am not able to write a method that gets
>   rid of these kind of circular references** like in the main method I
>   posted below.

It is a bit highlighted what needs attention imo.

The first thing is that the Java Garbage collector it will collect the **reachable** objects, and it will free those references.
The process is very similar, when you try to compile a project. In most of the cases all source files are compiled. But there are the few exceptions, same with the garbage collection.

Please take a look at this links:

[How does Java Garbage Collection work with Circular References?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/how-does-java-garbage-collection-work-with-circular-references)

[How does Java garbage collector deals with circular references when their access path is broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895618/how-does-java-garbage-collector-deals-with-circular-references-when-their-access)

I do really hope you don't want to fix the Java Garbage collector algorithm, because it isn't a beginner task.

My suggestion it is: **modify your code until you are fine with the Java garbage collector automatic circular reference free system.**